# INSERT PHP MYSQL não insere

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Estou com um simples problema com `INSERT` no `PHP` com `MYSQL` , acontece que não insere nada no banco de dados , já coloquei pra reportar os erros mas não funciona , estou usando vertrigo server

O código é esse :

```
<?php
 include '../config/config.inc.php';

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 //$usuario = $_POST['fu_usuario'];
 //$senha = $_POST['fu_senha'];
 //$email = $_POST['fu_email'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_cadastro (username,senha,email) VALUES ('teste','123','teste@gmail.com')" ;
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die (mysql_error());
 $num = mysqli_affected_rows($con);


   if($num > 0){
     echo "Usuario cadastrado com sucesso";
  }else{
    echo "Usuario não cadastrado";
  }


   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

código da conexão:

```
<?php 

   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","vertrigo")  or die 
("Erro de conexao ao BD --> ". mysql_error());
   mysqli_select_db($con,"dbsistema") or die("Erro de selecao do bd ". mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: Dá-te algum erro? Tens o `$con` defenido?

Comment: Amigo poste sua tabela sql e seu codigo mas é provavel que esteja faltando alguma virgula ou campo de inserção erado.

Comment: nao da nenhum erro , esse $con é a minha conexão

Comment: Erro dá, mas vc não está jogando ele na tela. Vide resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente é desatenção na hora de ver a documentação ou exemplos.

Você está usando uma função que não te serve para nada aqui: `or die( mysql_error() );`

De fato, `mysql_error()` sempre estará vazio neste contexto, pois não há comandos da `mysql` sendo executados, portanto, não há como se produzir erros detectáveis com esta função.

Agora, para obter erros da *lib* que você está usando de fato, que é a `mysqli`, você tem uma função adequada para obtenção de erros, que é esta aqui: [`mysqli_error($link)`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.error.php).

Aplicado ao seu caso:

```
$res = mysqli_query( $con, $sql ) or die( mysqli_error( $con ) );
```

E aqui precisa arrumar também:

```
$con = mysqli_connect( … )  or die( 'Erro de conexao ao BD: '.mysqli_error( $con ) );
mysqli_select_db( … ) or die( 'Erro de selecao do BD:'.mysqli_error( $con ) );
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda vou atentar sobre esses erros, mas eu dei um print na minha consulta ao banco de dados e verifiquei que que nao estava inserindo porque tinha que inserir em todos as colunas que existem na minha tabela , mas não entendi muito porque na criaçao das mesmas não disse que elas deveriam ser obrigatorias

Comment: O primeiro passo é realmente exibir os erros, e a partir daí fica bem fácil detectar onde está falhando.

Answer (score -1):

Está faltando você dizer ao mysqli_connect qual banco de dados voce usará para isso: mysqli_connect ($host, $user,$senha, $bandodedados).
Ou na sua query refira-se ao banco de dados ao qual voce irá utilizar (insert into bancodedados.tb_cadastro ...)

Comment: a função mysqli_select_db já faz isso

Comment: Ah, eu não havia visto. Sendo assim eu não vejo motivo para erro algum. Certifique-se de que sua query está funcionando. Teste ela em um phpMyAdmin, ou HeidiSQL...